# Close modal window after form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I have this in a php file from Contact Form 7, which **I load into a modal window** (FancyBox) and **I would like to close it after the user will press the Submit button**.

I was thinking of adding onSubmit="action" to the form but I don't know how or which one is the function I am supposed to use to close the modal window?

```
$form .= '<form action="' . esc_url_raw( $url ) . '" method="post"' . ' class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '"' . $enctype . '>' . "\n";
```

Is this the right approach?

Also, if I can make it to click on a PayPal button right after that, it will be brilliant.

Comment: Use `esc_url` instead of `esc_url_raw`, the raw version is for database storage and internal use inside of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact form 7 Lets you call a JavaScript function after the form has been submitted
You will find the Additional Settings field at the bottom of the contact form management page and you need to use the hook named `on_sent_ok` something like this:

```
on_sent_ok: "$.fancybox.close();"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This did the trick for me, and it was so simple. Is it possible to chain/trigger a click on a certain link/button I have on the page after the modal window is closed?

Comment: yeah you can create a JS function that will do what ever you want.

Comment: I was looking so long for this, in case anyone else needs the same thing, there you go: `on_sent_ok: "$.fancybox.close(); document.getElementById('paynow').click();"` where paynow is the id of the submit button.

Comment: But the problem with this line is that one is jQuery and the other JavaScript and I think that's why the modal gets closed, then a new tab is opened, even if the user doesn't fill in the required fields. How would I write them both in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: @CristianDemetriad I just used on_sent_ok: "jQuery.fancybox.close();" and it worked changing $ to jQuery